# How can I retrieve input from the user in a .bat file?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch-file

I'm the using the command `dir /AD /B "\\computerName\users\" >> user_export.log`

Is it possible to create a batch file that asks the user to enter the **Computer Name** and then when the end user enters the computer name for it to be entered in the UNC name listed above, so `dir /AD /B "\\**INPUT VALUE ENTERED HERE**\users\"`

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9435607/516290

Answer (score 6):

It will be best to isolate the user input from the use of the input in a UNC name. So I could help with the user input:

Just use the set command to get the user response:

```
set /P response=INPUT VALUE PLEASE
dir /A/D /B "\\%response%\users\"
```

You can write more sophisticated prompts like

```
set /P response="INPUT VALUE HERE > "
```

but the double ticks aren't necessary for the set command. They are requiered to ignored the special character `>`. Further the visibility of the space characters in the prompt will be improved.

Comment: Because of your use of the ">" character in the prompt, the quotes _are_ necessary to avoid a syntax error (probably because it looks like output redirection to the shell program).